# Loop over data frame rows and apply function

Tags: r

So, I have this dataframe "dataset2" with 3000 rows.

Its basically something like that:

```
  carat cut_ord color clarity_ord price
1  1.22       4     4           3  7213
2  1.01       2     4           5  6027
3  0.71       3     6           5  2660
```

In some records, I have negative values for price. I need to change those to another value. 
I've tried to do it in so many ways. I'm looking for a simple resolution for this problem.

Some thing that I tried:
1:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dataset2)){
  if(dataset2$price < 0){
    dataset2$price = 326
  }  
}
```

2.

```
for( i in rownames(dataset2) ){
  if(dataset2$price < 0){
    dataset2$price = 326
  }
}
```

Comment: `dataset2$price[dataset2$price < 0] <- 326` this is vectorized, no loop needed.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly.